# If I make 66K per year (US-Pennsylvania, Single filer) and I give 3000 to a 5013-c organization How much in tax relief should I expect

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

Last year I calculated my taxes using Turbo-Taxes online edition.  When asked to enter in my Charitable donations (I did itemize) there was no place for me to enter the charities ID number, and I didn't see any change to the amount of taxes I owe.  Am I at a salary level where giving that much to charity is just about pointless?  If that is not the case, How can I make sure that this year I pay the appropriate amount in taxes?

Thanks

Comment: You say you itemized. Did you have any taxable income at all? If you did, the lowest marginal rate is 10% and a $3000 deduction means a tax difference of $300. You should have seen some difference. Tough to troubleshoot exactly why you didn't.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer TurboTax _asks_ the user to give information regarding itemized deductions, but does not put the information on Schedule A and use the total of Itemized Deductions instead of the Standard Deduction unless the former exceeds the latter. Thus, simply entering itemized deductions data into TurboTax does _not_ necessarily mean that the taxpayer's return used itemized deductions: TurboTax will use the Standard Deduction when it is more beneficial to do so -- unless the taxpayer insists on using Itemized Deductions and paying more taxes than strictly necessary.

Comment: @DilipSarwate ok sir you set me straight, I read "I did itemize" as meaning "I exceeded standard deduction and filed schedule A". You are suggesting this may simply not be the case.

Comment: And he is right.  I did not infact exceed standard deduction.  My question is why not?  Giving 3000 in one year to a charity is not much of a tax help I wager.  I still give to charities however.

Comment: "Myquestion is why not?" The standard deduction is set by law, and so only Congress can answer the question as to why it is set to its current value. As to why your itemized deductions did not exceed the standard deduction, that is because you did not have enough of them :-) For most people, home mortgage interest, real estate taxes on the home, and state income taxes are what helps push their itemized deduction total towards exceeding the standard deduction, but owning one's home is a personal lifestyle choice that some, especially singles, may prefer not to make at that stage of their lives.

Comment: I have always felt tax laws are slanted to homeowners in the U.S.  In my humble opinion tax law should not favor one or the other.  It should be neutral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Giving to charity, regardless of whether you get a charitable deduction, should not be viewed as a pointless exercise regardless of salary level. Give to a 
>   charity if you wish to support its mission (feed the poor, heal the sick,
>   protect the environment, etc); don't if you do not.

Turning to your point, you get a *specific* deduction for a charitable contribution if you *itemize* your deductions on your Federal tax return. 
There can be some
limitations on this for extraordinarily generous philanthropists but this does
not seem relevant here. You are also entitled to *not* itemize your deductions but simply claim the *Standard Deduction* for your filing status (Single)
*if you choose to do so*. TurboTax is set up to compare the Standard Deduction
with the total of itemized deductions that you have entered into TurboTax, and use
the larger of the two numbers automatically as your Deduction (because doing
so reduces your overall tax due), but it *does* provide you
with the opportunity to refuse to use the Standard Deduction
and instead use the sum-total of your itemized deductions even though 
this will cause you to pay more income tax. If you used TurboTax's
step-by-step entry of data and answering of questions methodology,
it probably told you that it was using the Standard Deduction because
your itemized deductions totaled something smaller, and asking you
to specifically choose the "Use Itemized Deductions even though
they are less than the Standard Deductions" if you wished to do so.

Check your Federal tax return from last year. If you filed Schedule A
with your 2011 return, you probably got to deduct your charitable 
contributions explicitly. If you
didn't file Schedule A, you used the Standard Deduction and so *did* get
to deduct more than what you could have deducted as itemized deductions
(including any charitable contributions you made last year) but your
charitable contributions have
not been shown *explicitly* as having been deducted on your tax return.
This year is likely to be the same unless you bought a house/condo
and are making mortgage payments, paid lots of state income tax with your
PA income tax return in April 2012, etc., all of which activities 
lead to increased Itemized Deductions and improve your chances of
having the sum total exceed the Standard Deduction.